# Creating objects at run time

Tags: c#, object, runtime

Is there a way for creating objects at run time in c#?

for simplicity, assume the following problem..
if I have this class..

```
class student {
string name;
int ID;}
```

lets say I am writing a program that takes from the user the No. of students (e.g 15) the program then should create 15 objects from the  student class and ask the user to fill the name and the ID for each student.

What I want to know is how I could create objects at run time?

Comment: That's what the new command is for.

Comment: You don't need to add C# to the end of your title.  That is why we have tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should think about a object to save all the instances you are going to create.
Perhaps a [List< Student >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)..
Then you can use a [for-loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ch45axte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to create every single instance (using the new keyword) you like.
Inside the loop you can acquire user inputs to set the instance values (the student's name and ID).

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way for creating objects at run time in c#?

Since you know the type of the objects that you want to create at compile time you could use a [`List<Student>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to represent a dynamic collection of those objects that you could add elements to. Then at runtime you could you would ask the user to input the number of students to create and you will loop through this number and use the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) method on the list to add new elements to it.

As far as creating an instance of an object is concerned (`Student` in your case) you could simply invoke its [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) using the `new` keyword.

If the type of the objects that you want to create is not known at compile time you might need to resort to [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) in order to create instances of them dynamically at runtime.

And before you ask, the answer is no, I am not going to write the code for you until you show some efforts to do this homework assignment.